# mpv freezing with "stream suspended"

Tags: mpv

`mpv 0.35.1-dirty Copyright © 2000-2023`

`6.3.1-arch1-1`

MPV has  been working well until the external disk became unplugged. After replugging and remounting, MPV will not play. It starts the video (mkv) and then stops with this error. VLC plays without error.

```
  (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 1280x720 23.976fps)
  (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (ac3 6ch 48000Hz)
     Subs  --sid=1 --slang=eng 'ASS' (ass)
     Subs  --sid=2 --slang=eng 'ASS SDH' (ass)
     Subs  --sid=3 --slang=eng (subrip)
     Subs  --sid=4 --slang=eng 'SDH' (subrip)
 [ao/pulse] The stream is suspended. Bailing out.
 AO: [alsa] 48000Hz stereo 2ch float
 VO: [gpu] 1280x720 yuv420p
 AV: 00:00:00 / 01:33:34 (0%) A-V:  0.000 Cache: 172s/150MB
```

Comment: Worked for me via the "Windows method" : disconnected the bluetooth speaker and reconnected.